# How to get 'summary' to work with custom class in R

Tags: r, package

I'm wondering how I can get the `summary(object)` to work with a custom class in a package I'm creating. For example, if you run the following:

```
testfunction <- function(x) {
  x.squared <- x^2
  x.double <- 2*x
  x.triple <- 3*x

  result <- list(squared = x.squared, double = x.double, triple = x.triple)
  class(result) <- "customclass"
  result
}

x <- rnorm(100)
output <- testfunction(x)
summary(output)
```

you will see that the output is quite useless. I can't, however, seem to find how to control this output. If someone could direct me towards something I'd be grateful.

(I could, of course, make a custom summary function such as `summary.Custom(object)`, but I'd prefer to have the regular `summary` method working directly.

Comment: The way you control it is by writing your own summary method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a function called `summary.customclass` with the same arguments as `summary` (see `args(summary)` for that).

What you are doing there is creating a method of `summary` for an S3 class. You might want to read up on S3 classes.

Comment: Since this is for a package, it's worth mentioning the NAMESPACE file and (a) since summary is defined in the base package, the generic does not need to be imported before use; (b) the method needs to be registered and exported with \S3method(summary, customclass); and (c) the method needs to be documented on a man page with \alias{summary.customclass} and in the usage section \S3method{summary}{customclass}(object, ...). This is described in `RShowDoc("R-exts")`. Also worth clarifying that one would invoke this method with `summary(output)`, rather than with the full name of the method.

Comment: I got it working, thanks! I didn't realize that writing a function summary.customclass would change the summary function for objects belonging to the customclass. And @MartinMorgan I might be back for some elaboration on the things you mention... I have some issues with show-method being displayed in my description file. But that's for another question some other time :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `summary.list` function. If you want to use the `summary.default` function, you need to use `lapply` or `sapply`:

```
> lapply(output, summary)
$squared
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 0.000013  0.127500  0.474100  1.108000  1.385000 11.290000 

$double
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-6.7190 -1.0480  0.4745  0.3197  1.8170  5.1870 

$triple
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-10.0800  -1.5720   0.7117   0.4796   2.7260   7.7800
```

Or:

```
> sapply(output, summary)
          squared  double   triple
Min.    1.347e-05 -6.7190 -10.0800
1st Qu. 1.275e-01 -1.0480  -1.5720
Median  4.741e-01  0.4745   0.7117
Mean    1.108e+00  0.3197   0.4796
3rd Qu. 1.385e+00  1.8170   2.7260
Max.    1.129e+01  5.1870   7.7800
```