# S3 summary method for an object in R

Tags: r

I am a novice in R and I have this question which I have struggled to decode what I am needed to do.
"Write an S3 summary method for an object of class WeatherData which produces the following statistical summaries the rain, maxtp, mintp, maxgt variables split by season: mean, standard deviation, minimum, maximum. Ignore the missing values in the calculations".

The object I am dealing with contains the Historical Monthly Data recorded at the Dublin Airport
 ́Met Eireann Weather Observing Station from November 1941 to May 2019. (Source: https://www.met.ie/climate/available-data/historical-data).

How do I proceed with it?

Comment: This should fill you in: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get 'summary' to work with custom class in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684229/how-to-get-summary-to-work-with-custom-class-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea of how it works

```
library(pryr)  # only for otype

x <- 1
attr(x, "class") <- "foo"
otype(x)
summary.foo <- function(x){
 cat("Oh boy, it still is", x)
}
summary(x)
```

Read on [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s3)

What your summary function actually does, depends on the object. Could be a plot, some deep analyses, or summary on a subsample or whatever rows your boat, I mean, what seem appropriate.

Familiarize yourself with dplyr is my advice. You look for something along the lines of

```
library(dplyr)
weather %>%
group_by(season) %>%
summarise(avg_rain = mean(rain, na.rm = T,
          max_t = max(temp, na.rm = T)
```

Comment: “Error: object 'otype' not found” (and this part isn’t relevant for your answer anyway).

Comment: @Konrad, was not clear to me if it is about classes or data transformation. First I thougth it was classes. Maybe I was wrong